# installation of bugzilla fails on windows 10 showing error 500

Tags: perl, cpan, bugzilla, testlink

THE FOLLOWING ERROR IS SHOWING UP:

```
D:\Programs\XAMPP\htdocs\test\bugzilla-5.0.3>ppm install TimeDate
Downloading ActiveState Package Repository packlist...not found
ppm install failed: Can't find any package that provides TimeDate
```

Please help me on this,
perl is installed - ActiveState 5.26 
apache also confidured kindly suggest whr i am doing the mistake?
Actually after this my aim is to link it with Testlink.

Comment: Voting to close as typo. The OP simply mispelled the name of a module.

Answer (score 1):

The name of the module is "DateTime" (not "TimeDate").

[Installation instructions](https://bugzilla.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installing/windows.html#perl-modules)